# Can we use something other than a Salesforce User Account to access the REST API?

Tags: rest-api, oauth

We're accessing the Salesforce REST API with one of our regular Salesforce user accounts. That use changed his password, which is a good thing, but that invalidated our OAuth token, which meant we had to update and redeploy our web app.

We really don't want to have to pay for another Salesforce account just to make a few REST API calls. Is there a free (or at least cheaper) account type that we could create to make those API calls?

This is the connection string format we're using, which does seem odd...like we have too much stuff in there. I'm inheriting this code. By supplying a token, username and password shouldn't be needed and I'm wondering if by supplying it and the token that the REST API is simply using the username/password properties instead of the tokens.

```
<add name="SalesforceLogin" connectionString="Username=___; Password=___; Token=___; ConsumerKey=___; ConsumerSecret=___; redirectUri=___;" providerName="NetToSalesforce.Salesforce" />
```

I believe we are only reading data, not updating/inserting/deleting.

Thanks!

Comment: It all depends what information your accessing. What are the objects you are querying?

Comment: Changing the password shouldn't invalidate any oauth refresh tokens, which oauth flow are you using?

Comment: personally, i like to have all my external systems use a dedicated user seat (each) as it makes traceability and access control so much easier

Comment: @superfell it doesn't look like this is an OAuth flow at all (despite that mention in the question). The token that became invalid is the Security Token, which was reset when the password was changed.

Comment: Should update it to generate a refresh token and login that way.